# jquery <span> inside next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get this so that it rotates through LI's, and will fadein the SPAN within that LI after and before the next slide.

heres my code:

```
        var current = ($('.slider ul li.current'));
    var currentspan = ($('.slider ul li.current span'));
    var next = (current.next().length) ? current.next() : $('.slider ul li:first');
    var nextspan = (current.next('span').length) ? current.next('span') : $('.slider ul li:first span');
```

The problem is my nextspan variable has to be wrong. All i want to do is grab the SPAN inside the NEXT LI. as you can see the next variable gets set fine - so how do i get the span inside that next variable?

Comment: What's your markup look like?  Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

next() only gets the next sibling. So as the span is a child of the next li you'll have to do something like this:

```
current.next().find('span')
```